# Microsoft DirectAccess: Unable to Get Forced Tunneling to Connect After Defining Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, windows-server-2012-r2

We are currently in the process of setting up a test environment to use Forced Tunneling with Direct Access.

We have gone through the process of setting up the following steps from this [blog](https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2017/07/27/directaccess-force-tunneling-and-proxy-server-configuration/).

Configure a Proxy Server

Once force tunneling has been enabled, run the following PowerShell script to configure an on-premises proxy server for DirectAccess clients to use. Be sure to substitute the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) and port for your proxy server in the $proxy variable below.

```bsh
$gpo = (Get-RemoteAccess).ClientGpoName
$gpo = $gpo.Split(‘\’)[1]

$proxy = “proxy.corp.example.net:8080”

$rule = (Get-DnsClientNrptRule -GpoName $gpo | Where-Object Namespace -eq “.” | Select-Object -ExpandProperty “Name”)

Set-DnsClientNrptRule -DAEnable $true -DAProxyServerName $proxy -DAProxyType “UseProxyName” -Name $rule -GpoName $gpo
```

If multisite is enabled and Windows 7 clients are supported, run the following PowerShell script on one DirectAccess server in each entry point.

```bsh
$downlevelgpo = (Get-RemoteAccess).DownlevelGpoName
$downlevelgpo = $downlevelgpo.Split(‘\’)[1]

$proxy = “proxy.corp.example.net:8080”

$downlevelrule = (Get-DnsClientNrptRule -GpoName $downlevelgpo | Where-Object Namespace -eq “.” | Select-Object -ExpandProperty “Name”)

Set-DnsClientNrptRule -DAEnable $true -DAProxyServerName $proxy -DAProxyType “UseProxyName” -Name $downlevelrule -GpoName $downlevelgpo
```

These settings are then applied to the machine and we can see that proxy server settings are valid however we get "no internet access" and it looks like Direct Access does not connect.

I am unable to find any documentation to explain this issue we are having.